# Calendly webhook returning all events created instead of just one

Tags: node.js, express, axios, webhooks, calendly

Hi Im using Calendly webhook API to capture an event as soon as it is created from the the widget,
It works fine but my only problem is that my route first returns the current event and then after that it enters an infinite loop state returning all the other unwanted events, so this becomes a problem because I want to capture information of that event in a database and as well as send an email so with all the infinite executions my db and email is getting spammed

this how I created my webhook

```
  // Create a new webhook
  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://api.calendly.com/webhook_subscriptions',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer <MY_TOKEN>`,
    },
    data: {
      url: '<MY_ENDPOINT>',
      events: ['invitee.created'],
      organization:'<MY_ORGANIZATION>',
      scope: 'organization'
    }
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log('Webhook created:', response.data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Webhook creation failed:', error.response.data);
  });
});
```

This is the route that retrieves data passed

```
app.post('/calendly-webhook', (req, res) => {
  // Retrieve real-time data from the request payload
  const data = req.body;

  // Log the data to the console
  console.log('Calendly webhook data:', data);

  res.send('Webhook received');
});
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
```